# IllegalStateException can not perform this action after onsaveinstancestate

Tags: android, replace, screen, orientation, illegalstateexception

I read many threads to this topic but nothing could help me.
I can´t post my code, but i try to explain my situation:

I´m getting an IllegalStateException: can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

I have an activity Main (with an DrawerLayout / navigation drawer). In this activity is always 1 fragment. At first there is the fragment WelcomePage.

When the user clicks the fragment gets replaced with new fragment (I call it: FootballClubs). This fragment contains a ViewPager, so it consists of multi pages; each page is a fragment FootballClub. (So the fragment FootballClubs consists of multi pages of one FootballClub fragment). In each FootballClub fragment is a button where the user can click; on click opens a new fragment (I call it NewFragment).

At first, everything is ok and no exception is thrown. I can click the button as often as possible, each time the new fragment is shown correctly without an exception, and onBackPressed I get back to FootballClubs with the ViewPager. But when I turn my smartphone, screen orientation has changed at least one time, I get following exception when I click on the button to open the new fragment (whatever fragment I want to show):

IllegalStateException: can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

I replace the fragments WelcomePage/FootballClubs/NewFragment with this code:

```
protected void replaceSubfragment(int containerID, Fragment newFragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(containerID, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();
}
```

The exception is thrown in transaction.commit();
containerID is always the same (FrameLayout in activity layout)

Some additional information:

- If I replace
  transaction.commit();
  with
  transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
  I get this Exception: IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed (although I click/do exactly the same)
- All fragments gets replaced in my FragmentActivity class Main; When you click on the button, the Subclass of SectionPage gets noticed and calls a listener from FragmentActivity, so that the FragmentActivity can replace the fragments (BaseActivity gives the listener over to FootballClubs fragment, and this gives it over to the Subclass of SectionPage)
- Due to the fact that I only replace fragments in my FragmentActivity I don´t use getChildFragmentManager(); (As far as I can remember this didn´t work too)
- I know that the activity gets destroyed and recreated by the system when orientation changed, but I can´t do something with this information.. the whole app works perfectly except this button
- If I want to show a dialog instead of NewFragment on button click I get an IllegalStateException too
- In my FragmentActivity, I have a variable activeModule; here I can check activeModule.isAdded(); When the exception is thrown, isAdded() return false.. So I can check if the error will be thrown or not

I hope I could describe my problem. The screen orientation ruins everything, don´t know why..
If you need further information ask me.. if you need some code pieces maybe I can post something.

Thanks!

Comment: I feel certain that the exception is because of the ViewPager, but I didn´t find a solution. Finnally, I found a good way to avoid calling 'NewFragment'; now I don´t get this exception. I don´t need an answer anymore.